# Autolayout breaks when presenting a UITableViewController in a UIModalPresentationPageSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c

**EDIT :**  I have managed to pin it down to the culprit : **UIModalPresentationPageSheet** (same with UIModalPresentationFormSheet)

If I remove this and make a simple UIModal, the autolayout doesn't break… However, I still haven't managed to find the workaround but I guess UIModalPresentationPageSheet must recalculate the width of the table and break the constraints.

I have tried updating constraints after ViewDidLoad and ViewDidAppear… but to no avail.

I've been trying to figure out why my Autolayout breaks.
My initial layout was more complex but I broke it down to it's most simple expression and it still breaks.

Here is my initial settings of the cell :

[image]
[image]

Here are the constraints for the Label :

[image]

And here are the constraints for the UITextView :

[image]

And finally here is the absurd result… The UILabel has vanished… or so it seems because if I log it's CGSize… I get absurd height and width.

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: are there any warnings in Xcode console about layout constraints ?

Comment: for your label remove trailing space to :tire de... equals 8

Comment: @VinayJain : No. Not a single XCode warning.

Comment: @Robin : tried that. Doesn't change anything. Not a single thing :(

Comment: increase your label y value into 2 and reduce lable hieght into 40 and add top space and bottom space constraints.. just try

Comment: @Robin nope. Doesn't change anything. It all seems to be related to UIModalPresentationPageSheet and/or UIModalPresentationFormSheet. If I just make it a "normal" Modal the layout does not break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width is set as 722 for the UITextView in the UI which would take effect if constraints are missing for the label in the iPad size class.

Is there any chance you have been using size classes which do not reflect Regular Width Regular Height for the label constraint? I would check all your constraints are installed for this size class as it looks to me like the label is not present in the iPad size class.

Check what it looks like in the preview window for different devices. That should show which layouts are working and which are not.

**Edit: Solution found from discussion**

Interestingly, I wonder if the size class is different in a modal presentation with page or form? When you use a popover, the width size class changes to compact. Try using modal FullScreen just to see if that is the issue? Also look at [self.traitCollection] in the debugger to see what size class it is using.

I have found it best to use size class Any/Any for most development and then add exceptions.

Comment: I have checked that the label is present in the correct size class and it is… Also, tough I hadn't thought about checking in the preview… after a quick but thorough check, the preview actually display what I am expecting it to display. But not the build. I am guessing the problem arouses from the fact I am calling it via a UIModalPresentation…

Comment: What do you see if you rotate the simulator horizontal?

Comment: It remains broken in the simulator but NOT in the preview…

Comment: Final suggestion is to delete the app from the simulator like you would on the real device by holding the mouse down on the app, restart the simulator, do a build clean then do a build and run just to rule out that the simulator has not got messed up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that was one of my very first tests. And it failed. I am quite positive it has something to do with UIModalPresentationPageSheet and UIModalPresentationFormSheet messing up the Autolayout.

Comment: Interestingly, I wonder if the size class is different in a modal presentation with page or form? When you use a popover, the width size class changes to compact. Try using modal FullScreen just to see if that is the issue? Also look at `[self.traitCollection]` in the debugger to see what size class it is using.

Comment: YOU ROCK !! Thats is EXACTLY what it is. Could you Put this in ans answer so that I can mark it as correct ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your label is attached to textview and textview is attached to label, it doesnt know width of any of those components thats why its behaving like this.
You need to set width constraint of at least one component. Or you can attach your label to superview and then attach your textview to your label.

Comment: In the screen shot the label is pinned leading edge to the supeview, then pinned to the text view which is pinned to the trailing edge of the superview. The hugging priority is also different, so the label should be the width of the label text and the UITextField should fill the remainder by growing. This all looks correct to me. Both parties always reference each other when viewed from either end as has been shown?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel problem is label's trailing edge is pinned to textview and textview's leading edge is pinned to label. If you set width of label instead of trailing edge and leave leading edge of textview pinned to label, it should fix it.

Comment: @ALL : Rory is right, the width should be that of the Label. And even when setting the width explicitly the problem remains.